# Where can I find "manipulate" nodes

Tags: houdini

I'm following a beginners tutorial for Houdini 15, I'm using version 19. The tutorial shows a "Manipulation" area, where can I find the equivalent tools in v19?

**Tutorial screenshot (v15):**

[image]

**My v19:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately video editing/ VFX software is generally off topic here. Might be better to post this on Video Production Stack Exchange.  You can flag your question and ask the mods to migrate it for you if you want.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks :)

Comment: The flag button doesn't do anything for me, maybe because I'm not fully signed up. I've since found out the answer to my question, so if any mods happen to stumble across this, feel free to delete.

Comment: I think you should be able to delete the question yourself, since nobody has answered it yet.  But you don't have to worry, the question will likely be closed eventually since it's off-topic.